# Capacity management - what metrics/KPI for CPU and RAM?

Tags: memory, central-processing-unit, capacity-planning

Context: business applications servers

What are good metrics/KPI for measuring CPU usage and performance? I think that things like %usage are not really relevant (it's not because my PC uses 100% CPU at one point that i need to buy a new one). How can i anticipate the point where i need to add more computing power?

What are good metrics/KPI for measuring RAM usage and performance? How can i anticipate the point where i need to add more RAM?

Are there industry-recognized general ratios for the above metrics? (e.g.  should be < xyz unit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those metrics are mostly for OS developers: if you want specu=ifically to know about cpu and memory, then you want cpu-seconds actually used vs load, memory vs load, and io to the paging device vs load

The first will rise to your capacity, then plateau
The second will rise, start to plateau, and then the third will show a step upwards at that same load.

If you want a good general indicator, look at cpu run-queue length. Think of 0-1 as 0-100% cpu, and numbers above 1 as overload.  By about 4 per cpu core, the system never catches up in quiet milliseconds, and you're in trouble (;-))

--dave

Comment: cpu run-queue length seems a good lead, any idea for something similar on the RAM side?

Comment: Ram and cache are load-dependant queuing centres, which are odd.  They have a small and near-fixed cost until you run out of memory, at which time they suddenly turn into the *disk* queue of the swap device. Teamquest Model does memory if you ask, but they admit it pretty hard.

I suspect they do a load-dependant queuing centre that reads data from the swap-disk queuing centre.  I can do that by eye from vmstat and Solaris iostat, but I there isn't a good tool for it that I know about.

Answer (score 2):

This can not be answered because it depends on what you do application wise. Generally on an application level you do not care about those - you care about application level metrics (average response time per request, to be "simple").

Comment: the question is what do i have to put in place on those components (cpu&ram) to predict that i will be in trouble in x days/weeks/months from now, application metrics can display good levels until you go past some CPU/RAM threshold and where things crumble

Comment: Your brain. There are software packages that can collect information about utilization. Moving from this to a forecast model is very application specific. Which is where a smart person comes in and starts thinking how to model this.